# Converting multiple .py files to .exe

Tags: python, exe

I needed some help converting my .py project file to .exe, when I run the program it works on my computer perfectly with no errors but when I send it to somebody else the main .py file does not load the other .py files which are different GUI that pop up. I am using pyinstaller to convert to .exe, does anybody have any idea on how to fix the issue because I have a lot .py files that communicate with each other. Or if there is a better way to build a .exe

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)?

For converting, they provide a single file selection as well as a whole directory in which all your other files are there. You should try it.

Comment: idk i have herd it is not so reliable